# Position slider navigation outside of container

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, slider

Im working on creating a slider with some specific settings that i cant figure out.

```js
/*
 * Basic jQuery Slider plug-in v.1.3
 *
 * http://www.basic-slider.com
 *
 * Authored by John Cobb
 * http://www.johncobb.name
 * @john0514
 *
 * Copyright 2011, John Cobb
 * License: GNU General Public License, version 3 (GPL-3.0)
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 *
 */(function(e){"use strict";e.fn.bjqs=function(t){var n={width:700,height:300,animtype:"fade",animduration:450,animspeed:4e3,automatic:!0,showcontrols:!0,centercontrols:!0,nexttext:"",prevtext:"",showmarkers:!0,centermarkers:!0,keyboardnav:!0,hoverpause:!0,usecaptions:!0,randomstart:!1,responsive:!1},r=e.extend({},n,t),i=this,s=i.find("ul.bjqs"),o=s.children("li"),u=null,a=null,f=null,l=null,c=null,h=null,p=null,d=null,v={slidecount:o.length,animating:!1,paused:!1,currentslide:1,nextslide:0,currentindex:0,nextindex:0,interval:null},m={width:null,height:null,ratio:null},g={fwd:"forward",prev:"previous"},y=function(){o.addClass("bjqs-slide");r.responsive?b():E();if(v.slidecount>1){r.randomstart&&L();r.showcontrols&&x();r.showmarkers&&T();r.keyboardnav&&N();r.hoverpause&&r.automatic&&C();r.animtype==="slide"&&S()}r.usecaptions&&k();if(r.animtype==="slide"&&!r.randomstart){v.currentindex=1;v.currentslide=2}s.show();o.eq(v.currentindex).show();r.automatic&&(v.interval=setInterval(function(){O(g.fwd,!1)},r.animspeed))},b=function(){m.width=i.outerWidth();m.ratio=m.width/r.width,m.height=r.height*m.ratio;if(r.animtype==="fade"){o.css({height:r.height,width:"100%"});o.children("img").css({height:r.height,width:"100%"});s.css({height:r.height,width:"100%"});i.css({height:r.height,"max-width":r.width,position:"relative"});if(m.width<r.width){o.css({height:m.height});o.children("img").css({height:m.height});s.css({height:m.height});i.css({height:m.height})}e(window).resize(function(){m.width=i.outerWidth();m.ratio=m.width/r.width,m.height=r.height*m.ratio;o.css({height:m.height});o.children("img").css({height:m.height});s.css({height:m.height});i.css({height:m.height})})}if(r.animtype==="slide"){o.css({height:r.height,width:r.width});o.children("img").css({height:r.height,width:r.width});s.css({height:r.height,width:r.width*r.slidecount});i.css({height:r.height,"max-width":r.width,position:"relative"});if(m.width<r.width){o.css({height:m.height});o.children("img").css({height:m.height});s.css({height:m.height});i.css({height:m.height})}e(window).resize(function(){m.width=i.outerWidth(),m.ratio=m.width/r.width,m.height=r.height*m.ratio;o.css({height:m.height,width:m.width});o.children("img").css({height:m.height,width:m.width});s.css({height:m.height,width:m.width*r.slidecount});i.css({height:m.height});h.css({height:m.height,width:m.width});w(function(){O(!1,v.currentslide)},200,"some unique string")})}},w=function(){var e={};return function(t,n,r){r||(r="Don't call this twice without a uniqueId");e[r]&&clearTimeout(e[r]);e[r]=setTimeout(t,n)}}(),E=function(){o.css({height:r.height,width:r.width});s.css({height:r.height,width:r.width});i.css({height:r.height,width:r.width,position:"relative"})},S=function(){p=o.eq(0).clone();d=o.eq(v.slidecount-1).clone();p.attr({"data-clone":"last","data-slide":0}).appendTo(s).show();d.attr({"data-clone":"first","data-slide":0}).prependTo(s).show();o=s.children("li");v.slidecount=o.length;h=e('<div class="bjqs-wrapper"></div>');if(r.responsive&&m.width<r.width){h.css({width:m.width,height:m.height,overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"});s.css({width:m.width*(v.slidecount+2),left:-m.width*v.currentslide})}else{h.css({width:r.width,height:r.height,overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"});s.css({width:r.width*(v.slidecount+2),left:-r.width*v.currentslide})}o.css({"float":"left",position:"relative",display:"list-item"});h.prependTo(i);s.appendTo(h)},x=function(){u=e('<ul class="bjqs-controls"></ul>');a=e('<li class="bjqs-next"><a href="#" data-direction="'+g.fwd+'">'+r.nexttext+"</a></li>");f=e('<li class="bjqs-prev"><a href="#" data-direction="'+g.prev+'">'+r.prevtext+"</a></li>");u.on("click","a",function(t){t.preventDefault();var n=e(this).attr("data-direction");if(!v.animating){n===g.fwd&&O(g.fwd,!1);n===g.prev&&O(g.prev,!1)}});f.appendTo(u);a.appendTo(u);u.appendTo(i);if(r.centercontrols){u.addClass("v-centered");var t=(i.height()-a.children("a").outerHeight())/2,n=t/r.height*100,s=n+"%";a.find("a").css("top",s);f.find("a").css("top",s)}},T=function(){l=e('<ol class="bjqs-markers"></ol>');e.each(o,function(t,n){var i=t+1,s=t+1;r.animtype==="slide"&&(s=t+2);var o=e('<li><a href="#">'+i+"</a></li>");i===v.currentslide&&o.addClass("active-marker");o.on("click","a",function(e){e.preventDefault();!v.animating&&v.currentslide!==s&&O(!1,s)});o.appendTo(l)});l.appendTo(i);c=l.find("li");if(r.centermarkers){l.addClass("h-centered");var t=(r.width-l.width())/2;l.css("left",t)}},N=function(){e(document).keyup(function(e){if(!v.paused){clearInterval(v.interval);v.paused=!0}if(!v.animating)if(e.keyCode===39){e.preventDefault();O(g.fwd,!1)}else if(e.keyCode===37){e.preventDefault();O(g.prev,!1)}if(v.paused&&r.automatic){v.interval=setInterval(function(){O(g.fwd)},r.animspeed);v.paused=!1}})},C=function(){i.hover(function(){if(!v.paused){clearInterval(v.interval);v.paused=!0}},function(){if(v.paused){v.interval=setInterval(function(){O(g.fwd,!1)},r.animspeed);v.paused=!1}})},k=function(){e.each(o,function(t,n){var r=e(n).children("img:first-child").attr("title");r||(r=e(n).children("a").find("img:first-child").attr("title"));if(r){r=e('<p class="bjqs-caption">'+r+"</p>");r.appendTo(e(n))}})},L=function(){var e=Math.floor(Math.random()*v.slidecount)+1;v.currentslide=e;v.currentindex=e-1},A=function(e){if(e===g.fwd)if(o.eq(v.currentindex).next().length){v.nextindex=v.currentindex+1;v.nextslide=v.currentslide+1}else{v.nextindex=0;v.nextslide=1}else if(o.eq(v.currentindex).prev().length){v.nextindex=v.currentindex-1;v.nextslide=v.currentslide-1}else{v.nextindex=v.slidecount-1;v.nextslide=v.slidecount}},O=function(e,t){if(!v.animating){v.animating=!0;if(t){v.nextslide=t;v.nextindex=t-1}else A(e);if(r.animtype==="fade"){if(r.showmarkers){c.removeClass("active-marker");c.eq(v.nextindex).addClass("active-marker")}o.eq(v.currentindex).fadeOut(r.animduration);o.eq(v.nextindex).fadeIn(r.animduration,function(){v.animating=!1;v.currentslide=v.nextslide;v.currentindex=v.nextindex})}if(r.animtype==="slide"){if(r.showmarkers){var n=v.nextindex-1;n===v.slidecount-2?n=0:n===-1&&(n=v.slidecount-3);c.removeClass("active-marker");c.eq(n).addClass("active-marker")}r.responsive&&m.width<r.width?v.slidewidth=m.width:v.slidewidth=r.width;s.animate({left:-v.nextindex*v.slidewidth},r.animduration,function(){v.currentslide=v.nextslide;v.currentindex=v.nextindex;if(o.eq(v.currentindex).attr("data-clone")==="last"){s.css({left:-v.slidewidth});v.currentslide=2;v.currentindex=1}else if(o.eq(v.currentindex).attr("data-clone")==="first"){s.css({left:-v.slidewidth*(v.slidecount-2)});v.currentslide=v.slidecount-1;v.currentindex=v.slidecount-2}v.animating=!1})}}};y()}})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Demo CSS - You do not need this css in your own slider */

body{
 font-family: "Open Sans", helvetica, arial;
}


#container{
 max-width:750px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-bottom:80px;
}

#banner-fade,
#banner-slide{
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}

ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{
 display:block;
 padding:10px;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration: none;
    border:  1px solid #ff00ff;
}

ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a:hover{
 color:#fff;
    
}

ol.bjqs-markers li a{
 padding:5px 10px;
 background:#000;
 color:#fff;
 margin:5px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ol.bjqs-markers li.active-marker a,
ol.bjqs-markers li a:hover{
 background: #999;
}

p.bjqs-caption{
    
}
/* Basic jQuery Slider essential styles */

ul.bjqs{position:relative; list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:; display:none;}
li.bjqs-slide{position:absolute; display:none;}
ul.bjqs-controls{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:9999;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0; height: 100%; width: 30%;cursor:url("right.cur"), auto;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0; height: 100%; width: 30%;cursor:url("left.cur"), auto;}
ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{text-align: center;}
ol.bjqs-markers li{display:inline;}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{display:inline-block;}
p.bjqs-caption{display:block;width:96%;margin:0;padding:2%;position:absolute;bottom:50; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  
    <title>Basic jQuery Slider - Demo</title>
      
    <!-- bjqs.css contains the *essential* css needed for the slider to work -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bjqs.css">

    <!-- some pretty fonts for this demo page - not required for the slider -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro|Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

    <!-- demo.css contains additional styles used to set up this demo page - not required for the slider --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">

    <!-- load jQuery and the plugin -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
      
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <div id="container">
  

      <!--  Outer wrapper for presentation only, this can be anything you like -->
      <div id="banner-fade">

        <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
        <ul class="bjqs">
          <li><img src="img/01.jpg" title="AUBSU"></li>
          <li><img src="img/02.jpg" title="Ststionsty"></li>
          <li><img src="img/03.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

      </div>
      <!-- End outer wrapper -->

      <script class="secret-source">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

          $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
            height      : 500,
            width       : 750,
            responsive  : true,
              showmarkers     : false, 
          });

        });
      </script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

Id like to position the navigation's outside the container and to be positioned in v and h center (see image for ref.)

http://i.gyazo.com/bc71b18b5e3f562d82cc9b6e4551e610.png

Also, moving the caption is something im working on too.

Comment: Please post what you've tried... your code, your examples. Giving this information doesn't give us a place to start or things to suggest.

Comment: my bad, hope this is appropriate...

Comment: its better, but we want to see what *you've* tried.

Comment: this is my attempt - this is my customized version of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the navigation outside of the slider is very straightforward, you just want to adjust the positioning via css.

```
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a {
  left: -49px;
}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a {
  right: -51px;
}
```

Simply adding these values position the nav outside of the element. As far as the caption goes, it's absolutely positioned inside of that element, so you'd want to look to `p.bjqs-caption` to see how you can change the CSS to allow it to be placed outside the slider. It may not be possible with how the script is written.

On my first attempt it just disappears under the slider, probably because it has an `overflow: hidden` on it.

Comment: Thanks. Its close, but not exactly what im looking for. I have made the container w: 100% and changed its color to demonstrate what im trying to achieve. Id like the link (pink border) to snap to the container as it resizes.

`#container{
 max-width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-bottom:80px;
    background-color: aqua;
}`